# Changing fill option in \addplot has no effect

Tags: pgfplots

```
 \addplot table [x=X, y=4ACH,fill=black,draw=black,bar shift=-0.5ex] {\datatable};
```

makes no difference to colour of bars.

[change color of pgfplot bar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99314/change-color-of-pgfplot-bar-plot) has the same problem but the workaround doesn't work for me. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? Also what's with the legend having two bars?

[image]
    \documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

```
\newcounter{groupcount}
\pgfplotsset{
    draw group line/.style n args={5}{
        after end axis/.append code={
            \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
            \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#1}\of\datatable\as\cell{%
                \def\temp{#2}
                \ifx\temp\cell
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=0
                        \stepcounter{groupcount}
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (startgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \else
                        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\datatable
                        \coordinate [yshift=#4] (endgroup) at (axis cs:\pgfplotsretval,0);
                    \fi
                \else
                    \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=base, yshift=0.5ex] {#3} (endgroup);
                    \fi
                \fi
            }
            \ifnum\thegroupcount=1
                        \setcounter{groupcount}{0}
                        \draw [
                            shorten >=-#5,
                            shorten <=-#5
                        ] (startgroup) -- node [anchor=base, yshift=0.5ex] {#3} (endgroup);
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
X   Gp           Name        4ACH 6ACH
1   Patient1    E   0.0002875   0.00004375
2   Patient1    P   0.0002  0.000133333
3   Patient1    H   0.000382716 0.000290123
4   Patient1    N   0.001195062 0.000562654
5   Patient1    F   0.00201962  0.0016803
6   {}  {}      0 0
7   Patient2    E   0.0002875   0.00004375
8   Patient2    P   0.000533333 0.0002
9   Patient2    H   0.000567901 0.000259259
10  Patient2    N   0.001503395 0.000477778
11  Patient2    F   0.00201962  0.0016803
12  {}  {}      0 0
13  Patient3    E   0.081057143 0.0934
14  Patient3    P   0.0758  0.025466667
15  Patient3    H   0.580506173 0.815259259
16  Patient3    N   0.977954012 0.770544444
17  Patient3    F   0.022212031 0.025019363
18  {}  {}      0 0
19  Patient4    E   0.0002875   0.00004375
20  Patient4    P   0.0758  0.025466667
21  Patient4    H   0.05982716  0.071154321
22  Patient4    N   0.426280247 0.618009568
23  Patient4    F   0.022212031 0.025019363

}\datatable

\begin{axis}[
    %axis lines*=left,
    %ymajorgrids,
    width=12cm, height=6cm,
    ymin=0,
    ybar,
    bar width=3pt,
    xtick=data,
    ymax=2.5,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{Name},
    xticklabel style={rotate=0,yshift=-1.5ex,xshift=0ex,anchor=mid },
    draw group line={Gp}{Patient1}{Patient1}{-6ex}{5pt},
    draw group line={Gp}{Patient2}{Patient2}{-6ex}{5pt},
    draw group line={Gp}{Patient3}{Patient3}{-6ex}{5pt},
    draw group line={Gp}{Patient4}{Patient4}{-6ex}{5pt},
    ylabel={CFU cm$^2$},
    after end axis/.append code={
        \path [anchor=base east, yshift=0.5ex]
            %(rel axis cs:0,0) node [yshift=-10ex]{Conc 1}
            %(rel axis cs:0,0) node [yshift=-7ex] {Conc 2}
            %(rel axis cs:0,0) node [yshift=-6ex] {Patient \#}
            ;
    }
]

\addplot table [x=X, y=4ACH,fill=black,draw=black,bar shift=-0.5ex] {\datatable}; \addlegendentry{4  ac.h$^{-1}$}
\addplot table [x=X, y=6ACH,fill=white,draw=black,bar shift=0.5ex] {\datatable}; \addlegendentry{6  ac.h$^{-1}$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The options need to be supplied to the `\addplot [...]` options, not the `table [...]`, so you have to say `\addplot [fill=black, draw=black, bar shift=-0.5ex] table [x=X, y=4ACH] {\datatable};`

Comment: D'oh! :=) Thank you for the quick response! By the way is there a GUI program which creates graphs for latex documents? I wish I could get the cm fonts for the pc then two mins in excel and job done. Messing about with the data and whatnot for that graph has taken 2 hours.

Comment: I don't know of a GUI specifically for that, although I guess `matlab2tikz` comes close. Personally, I think it's much easier to get consistent graphs quickly when using something like PGFPlots *without* a GUI: Once you've set up your plot styles, all you need to do is change the data file, and you're done.